# Limitar numero de elementos a mostrar

Tags: javascript, html, ionic

Tengo los siguientes elementos: Solo quiero mostrar un numero determinado en la vista.][ Por ejemplo, ahora solo tengo 8 elementos, me gustaría solo mostrar 3.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente cambias la fuente de tu lista, con slice puedes tomar solo algunos
elementos de tu lista.

```
let arrayElementos = [{elemento1}{elemento2}{elemento3}{elemnto4}{elemento5}];
 let elementosMostrar=  array.slice(0, 3);
```

https://api.jquery.com/slice/

agrega como estas mostrando tu lista para modificarla y mostrarte el proceso completo.

Comment: Gracias, me funciono, solo agrege .slice(0, 3); en el arrar y funciono como quería.

Comment: si estas usando angular puedes agregar una funcion pipe de la siguiente manera: *ngFor="let item of itemsArray|limitTo:3"